# SVG : line with y attribute expressed in percentage units does not get affected by viewBox

Tags: svg, viewbox

It seems that specifying line coordinates of an SVG line in percentages makes that coordinate exist in viewport coordinate system instead of the user coordinate system established by a viewBox. To me that sounds strange, especially after reading the specs.
In the example below, the green line is defined by user space coordinates while the blue line's y coordinate is in percentage units (50%). When the button is clicked, the viewBox is applied - the green line is scaled properly while the blue line is not ... What is going on there?
The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) says: 
*For any y-coordinate value or height value expressed as a percentage of the SVG viewport, the value to use must be the percentage, in user units, of the height parameter of the ‘viewBox’ applied to that viewport. If no ‘viewBox’ is specified, then the value to use must be the percentage, in user units, of the height of the SVG viewport.*

UPDATE: I grouped all elements in the svg and supplied transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" and the percentage coordinate worked as expected. I start suspecting that the viewBox only transforms coordinates specified in user units and not in explicit units. But I would think the percentage should not be considered as an explicit unit as it is not really physical value. And it would contradict the spec excerpt from above. So what is it ?

```js
function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById("maxi").setAttribute("viewBox","0,0,492,124");

}
```

```html
<svg id="maxi" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px"  width="246" height="62" font-size="23px" xml:space="preserve" >

   <line id="greenline" x1="0" y1="31" x2="232" y2="31" stroke="#00FF00" stroke-width="4"/>
      <line id="blueline" x1="0" y1="50%" x2="232" y2="50%" stroke="#0000FF"/>

            <path class="cutContour" fill="none" stroke="#EC008C" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M6.8,2.3H225
    c2.3,0,4.3,1.9,4.3,4.3v48.2c0,2.3-1.9,4.3-4.3,4.3H6.8c-2.3,0-4.3-1.9-4.3-4.3V6.6C2.5,4.2,4.4,2.3,6.8,2.3z"/>

</svg>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="myFunction();">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything unusual about the behaviour you're describing. See Codepen at https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/JapPQd.

The blue line is staying in the (vertical) centre of the SVG as its Y-coordinates are expressed as 50%. When the viewBox changes value, this is not affected. Only its X values are expressed in absolute terms so the line gets halved when the viewBox is made explicit.

The green line is getting displaced in X- and Y-axes when the button is clicked as the coordinate system is changing - in your example doubling - and its coordinates are expressed in absolute terms.

I changed the colours and stroke-widths to make it clearer what's going on. I've also commented out your PATH and put a (dotted) border round the SVG for clarity. I have also added a handy reset button:

```
function reset() {
  document.getElementById("maxi").removeAttribute("viewBox");
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I dont understand.As I see it (obviously wrongly) when the viewBox changes the coordinate system - the 50% should also adjust to the viewBox size... Can you please explain why it should not. thanks

Comment: You have two ways of specifying the coordinates of each shape. When you express a dimension as 50%, you're saying, "I want this width / height to be half of the entire SVG." When you express it as a number such as 232, you're saying, "In the coordinate system defined by the viewBox attribute, this dimension is 232 of those units." I must admit, I find your approach quite unusual as you're not specifying the viewBox initially. What are you trying to create anyway?

Comment: Thanks, MSC, I get it now. I use the same SVG in two places on my site. Once enlarged and the second time, smaller, as a thumbnail. Hence the dynamic vewBox. The reasons for using the y="50%" is that I have many different SVGs and I draw that line by means of code in each of the SVGs. I thought it will be cleaner to have the y coordinate be expressed as 50% and not to deal with BBox and calculating the middle of each SVG I work with.  I was thinking to have  an inner SVG with viewBox(0,0,100,100) to have  coordinates as percents and an outer SVG to actually shrink the whole SVG Will it work ?

Comment: Based on what you've described can't you just use "<img src='mysvg.svg' style='width: 100%'/>"? This will fit into any container (eg. a wrapper DIV) and scale proportionately. As this is just a comment, I can't easily share additional code unless you create a separate new question.

Comment: I have spawned a different question about how to solve my original question. Will appreciate if you could have a look, thanks   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271191/svg-have-line-centered-vertically-without-knowing-svg-height